# How to unwrap the value of promises in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code:

```
...
const array = nestings.map(async nesting =>
    await Promise.all([
        getFirstDataFromDB();
        getSecondDataFromDB();
        getThirdDataFromDB();
    ]);
        .then([data1, data2, data3]) => ({data1: data1, data2: data2, data3: data3}))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
...
console.log(array); // Promise
```

In the console.log I get promise, but how can I get the generated array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need *two* `Promise.all`s - one for every individual item, and then another over an array of those `Promise.all`s. When the `Promise.all` for the whole array resolves, you can `.map` its results to the array of objects you want:

```
const arrayOfProms = nestings.map(nesting => Promise.all([
  getFirstDataFromDB(),
  getSecondDataFromDB(),
  getThirdDataFromDB()
]));
const arrOfData = await Promise.all(arrayOfProms);
const array = arrOfData.map(
  ([data1, data2, data3]) => ({data1: data1, data2: data2, data3: data3})
);
```

Example snippet:

```js
const getData = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 200, 'someval'));
const nestings = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
(async () => {
  const arrayOfProms = nestings.map(nesting => Promise.all([
    getData(),
    getData(),
    getData()
  ]));
  const arrOfData = await Promise.all(arrayOfProms);
  const array = arrOfData.map(
    ([data1, data2, data3]) => ({data1: data1, data2: data2, data3: data3})
  );
  console.log(array);
})();
```